# Как отображать pdf без возможности копирования

Tags: html, pdf

Всем привет! Вопрос такой: как отображать документ в pdf формате доступном только для чтения, т. е. без возможности скачать или распечатать а так же выделить, вобщем исключить по максимому любую возможность копирования?

Answer (score 1):

Для этого надо сохранить pdf-файл с запретом печати и копирования - pdf-формат позволяет такое и Adobe Reader будет этого требования придерживаться. Впрочем, можно найти другие редакторы, которые так делать не будут.

С печатью бороться бесполезно, потому что всегда можно сделать скриншот, в том числе с помощью программ, умеющих делать прокручиваемый скриншот.

А вот с копированием - pdf - во многом графический формат и текст в нём имеет координаты. Например, если экспортировать файл из Open Office, то часть пробелов превращается в разрывы. Это можно использовать: разместить блоки с буквами в файле в рандомном порядке, но так, чтобы они визуально образовывали текст. Если это копировать, то скопируется каша из букв, а не текст. Но обращаю внимание, что такой фокус также лишит скринридеры возможности прочитать текст.

Про скачивание: чтобы просмотреть файл, его уже надо скачать, так что бороться со скачиванием бессмысленно.

Answer (score 0):

Если дать открыть pdf средствами браузера, то никак.
Если выводить картинкой то:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110130/protect-image-download

Comment: Pdf поддерживает запрет печати и копирования в самом документе.